Maling A 3D rigged StickMan
Recently I have been learning blender and I have really desired to create a 3D rigged stickman.The problem is I have watched all the tutorials but I still can't get the simple way to create the character that I want.I would like help from the start on how I would create the following model and how I would rig it easily. Also I would like help on texturing it and sculpting it so as to deform like on the second picture.



Hello, your question is too broad, please ask a precise question

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. You should show efforts towards reaching your goal, describing what you have tried and why it failed, so we don't risk recommending something you already know. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site. If you could [edit] your post to focus on where you are stuck we can vote to reopen it.

Have you tried the Skin modifier? With it, you can create a body and a "stick head". Then replace the "stick head with a "circle head" (add Curve > Circle, in Properties view, select (Curve) Data tab, go to Geometry > Bevel section, and increase Depth value). The Skin modifier can automatically create an armature for the model. Then you just need to parent the "circle head" to the head bone, and add eyes and a mouth.

Is there some new trend I missed? Your asking for a blue stickman that looks like the red stickman in another question... your username is "Just Easy", the other question is from "Just Max". Coincidence or did I miss something? Or did you create a second profile to ask the same question twice?

Hello, Just.. This does, indeed, look like a duplicate :) ... If you have a question that is clearly distinct  from the marked duplicate, albeit about the same subject-matter, please edit this post to link back to duplicate, pointing out the differences or new problems you are asking about, here.
